Is "The Shining" a title with a gerund, or a regular -ing noun?
Does using "the" or "a" in front of a gerund alter it somehow? "A painting," for example, is not a gerund, and if a book were titled "The Painting" it would not contain a gerund in the title. So do the titles "The Shining," "The Awakening" and "The Haunting of Hill House" contain gerunds?
I'm writing a discussion about verbs for a general audience, and this question arose in the section about gerunds. Does adding an article in front of the gerund change it, the way "Painting is my hobby" contains a gerund, but "The painting over there is horrid" does not?

The definition of a gerund is a present participle that acts as a noun, referring to the action of the verb. So these are all gerunds. However, "painting" long ago morphed from a gerund into a true noun; when we talk of "a painting", we're not talking about the action of painting (but it's still a gerund when you say "I enjoy painting").

The definition of a 'gerund' differs depending on who is using it. It is an ill-defined term. But 'the painting over there is by Guildford' is a deverbal noun (as Barmar says), while 'the painting of the 'Sunflowers' series by van Gogh' is not; it is further along the along the noun-verb continuum (nearer the nounal end) according to Quirk et al. Huddleston et al would lump all such intermediates together. // 'The shining' is a strange phrase, and the only clue ti POS is the definite article, hinting strongly at deverbal noun. But 'the shinings' doesn't seem available.

@EdwinAshworth If it takes adverbs and objects, it’s a verb. If it takes adjectives, it’s a noun. To a first approximation: ⑴ in Shining my shoes beautifully is fun it’s a verb; ⑵ in The laborious shining of shoes is so annoying it’s a noun; ⑶ in Bright, shining lights are blinding it’s an adjective. At no point does anyone ever need to pull in the disputed and oft-misapplied term ‘gerund’ to describe basic English syntax, nor should they: you should ɴᴏᴛ need a PhD in linguistics for simple things like these! People should just stop using the word ‘gerund’ altogether; it’s hopeless.

@tchrist You make it look so simple but I wonder if it's in keeping with the modern approach to grammar. I mean Huddleston, Pullum and others. Do we really need CaGEL?

@tchrist In "Shining shoes beautifully is fun", "shining is not a noun, but a verb -- it has a direct object. Was that a typo on yourpart?

@user405662 Yes, we need CGEL. It's the clearest and most accurate grammar available today. Its lead author, Rodney Huddleston, is the finest grammarian of the English language alive today.

@EdwinAshworth Gerund is perfectly well defined -- it's a verb, though we usually combine it with the present participle to form the 'gerund-participle' (again a verb). The ing noun form is best called a gerundial noun, or simply a noun. CGEL doesn't 'lump' anything together, as you put it, but looks for syntactic evidence to support one analysis or the other. I believe you have a copy of CGEL, so you should know that.

@BillJ I also have a copy of CoGEL.

@EdwinAshworth Ah yes, the out-of-date, woolly, bumbling Comprehensive, which H+P have proved to be wrong on many issues.

@BillJ or have adopted different analyses.

@BillJ  OOPS!! Yes, it was a typo. Fixed now. Thank you.

It's explained in the book that "shining" is a noun denoting a particular ability or skill, and "the shining" is therefore a noun phrase with the definite article; it appears to be non-countable, as is often the case with vague mystical things implied to be singular or unique (cf another film, The Sixth Sense). I don't know if the film explains this as clearly. Awakening is a countable noun in English, and you'll find it listed as such in dictionaries; it's commonly pluralised and modified by adjectives ("rude awakenings").

Thank you all very much! The discussion is fascinating and answers my question. Terrific help here!
